# The pollination of lupins

Tags: botany, entomology, ethology, bees, pollination

Do lupins produce nectar? According to [this study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167880921000906) it seems like there are conflicting conclusions regarding this. And in [this study](https://bsapubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ajb2.1613) the supposed inability for *Lupinus argenteus* to produce nectar is utilized to study whether the addition of nectar changes pollinator behaviour.

If the answer to this question is no, then why do [these bumblebees](https://youtu.be/HmdvqDtV1Xk) insert their tongue inside the base of the flower, because it certainly looks like that is what they are doing. Do they do so regardless of whether a flower contains nectar or not, just to verify whether there is any present in the flower? But if pollinators only visit lupins for pollen to eat then why do they stick their tongue inside the banner where it seems to me that there should be either trace amounts or no pollen at all.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the Tour before posting. That way you will find out how this site works. I have edited out reference to two questions, as we only take one at a time. I am no botanist, but did you really mean “banner”?

Comment: Yes, banner as in the uppermost part of a papilionacepus flower (zygomorphic flower shared by almost all plants of the pea family). My phrasing is not specific enough: the banner in this lupin flower is folded slightly towards the bottom creating a "crevice". It is this crevice that the bees in the video seemingly stick their tongue in.

Comment: Ok. Banner it is. I should stick to animals.

Comment: Is there some reason to think that all lupines must be the same? If so, then please [edit] that into your post. If not, then is *Lupinus argenteus* the species of interest and is that species what is being shown in the linked video? Also, what species is the bumblebee? ——— While providing links and sources is good you should also summarize what is in the papers and video; all posts must be self contained (i.e. must not require users to follow links). In addition, it would be great if you extracted and posted relevant frames or short segments as gifs from the video.

Comment: The lupine from the video appears to be _L. polyphyllus_, and [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/bf00396768) suggests _L. polyphyllus_ doesn't produce nectar.